# Teradata volatile table setting field too large

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to re-run an old query and have been hitting row size issues. After a few workarounds I've gotten all but two of the values added to the table that I need. Whenever I try to add the last two fields I get some form of "This will make the maximum row length too long" (depending on whether I'm running just the straight query or I include the `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE` ... etc. wrapping around the query.

Putting aside that there is no reason the data should cause the max row length to be exceeded (I should be pulling the exact same data as back in Feb. 2016 when this script was last successfully run), the only thing that I'm able to see that might be causing the issue is that two phone # fields as well as the field holding the address type show having a Max Length of 16000 when I run `HELP TABLE`. The phone #s are all only 10 characters (as expected) and the address type is only 4 characters at most.

So what I'm looking for help with is:

1. What would cause Teradata to throw errors about the row length being too long aside from there row length actually being too long (like I said it should be the same data and the script worked before, so I'm not 100% convinced something isn't just gacked on the server)
2. Is the Max Length of those 3 fields a likely candidate? If so, how do I force them to be smaller (again, when I run `LENGTH` on the values nothing returns as > 10 so 15990 of the 16000 is wasted)? And why would the fields be getting set to be larger on this run than on the prior run?
3. If the Max Lengths aren't the issue, what could I do to help diagnose the problem?

For reference, the portion of the script where I am stuck is below

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE
PCP_DATA_2
AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    PA.Prov_Nbr
    , PA.NPI
    , OREPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(SDA_MAP.State_Defined_SDA)), ' TEXAS', '') AS SDA
    , PA."First/Inst Name"
    , PA.Last_Name
    , PA.Degree
    , PA.Spec_Code
    , PA.Spec_Desc
    , PA.Hat_Code
    , PA.Hat_Desc
    , PA.Group_Nbr
    , PA.Group_Name
    , PA.Address1
    , PA.Address2
    , PA.City
    , PA.State
    , PA.Zip
    , UPPER(TRIM(SDA_MAP.STD_County_Name)) AS County
    , PA.Primary_Phone_Nbr
    , PA.Secondary_Phone_Nbr
    , PA.Address_Type
    , PA.Affstat_Code
    , PA.AfterHrs
    , PA.Affiliation_ID

FROM
    PCP_DATA AS PA

    LEFT JOIN V_REF_MD_CITY_COUNTY_SDA_CRSWK AS SDA_MAP
        ON PA.Zip = SDA_MAP.USPS_ZipCode
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Prov_Nbr)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

I know this question is on the broad side, but Google hasn't been turning up anything helpful & the other analysts in my group are just as stumped as I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this query worked before you had a different character set for your session.

When you get a  *9804: Response Row size or Constant Row size overflow* it's usually due to session using UTF-8 or UTF-16 as a character set.

The columns are probably defined as LATIN (i.e. a single byte per character), but for UTF-16 the size is doubled and for UTF-8 it's tripled. The maximum size of a result row is 64k and **3 * 16000 * (2|3)** clearly exceeds that (this is based on the defined size, not the actual size).

Cast the oversized columns to an appropriate size, this also increases the performance of DISTINCT, which expands VarChars to Chars.